# What are the different ways to invoke an AngularJS Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controlleras

Seeking clarification as to what I am missing from my AngularJS (1.5.6) code. The current source code I'm working with does the following:

1. Defines `var model` json
2. Calls `init()`
3. Runs `init()` which retrieves local storage and returns a query.

The following is an excerpt of the source code. Currently it is not working. The code intentions are to highlight the search box when it is not empty. Note: `queryFoo` is mockup i.e. a placeholder.

AngularJS

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module("myApp")
    .controller("fooController", fooController);

  function fooController() {
    var model = this;
    model.queryFoo = queryFoo;
    model.search = "";
    //model.styleSearch = 'search-empty';
    model.highlightActiveSearch = highlightActiveSearch;

    init();

    function init() {
      return queryFoo();
    }

    function highlightActiveSearch() {
      model.styleSearch = model.search.length >= 1
        ? "search-active"
        : "search-empty";
    }
  }
})();
```

CSS

```
.search-active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="fooController as fc">
  <input class="form-control input-sm valign" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="fc.search" ng-change="fc.highlightActiveSearch()" ng-class="fc.styleSearch" />
</div>
```

Comment: Apparently this code works fine after demonstrating at https://jsfiddle.net/nsuvsds0/ fiddle (ommiting the queryFoo()) and initializing the app module. You are missing something. Could you share some of the real code ?

Comment: What does 'Currently it is not working' mean and what does it have to do with the subject?

Comment: first of all, in the view you named the controller as fc, and in the controller itself you named model, try change fc to model. or model to fc. and try again.